# How can I install no longer available purchased software in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: software-center, games, proprietary

I bought the game Family Farm within the Software Center of Ubuntu 14.04 and installed it. The game is not available any more in the Software Center of Ubuntu 15.10. How can I install the purchased game in a later Ubuntu version?

Comment: You may need to contact the developers for instructions: http://www.familyfarmgame.com/en/family-farm-game

Comment: Most likely this software can not be installed into 15.10. Maybe it can.

Answer (score 0):

Based on their website (including broken links) I'd say this game is no longer supported and you are out of luck:
http://www.familyfarmgame.com/en/linux-downloads

However the developer can be found here:
http://www.hammerware.cz/contact

Try providing your credentials to the dev listed and ask if there is a tarball of the game.  Outlook is not good.